# SPEEDLINK MEDUSA NX 5.1 this is how to setup

Tags: headphones

I just bought this headphones and i wondered how do i set them up when there is no linux driver for. http://www.speedlink.com/?p=2&cat=41A3&pid=27063&paus=1
I am using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: yes u are right, but some peaple might not know how to set this up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to setup this headphones you need PulseAudio volume control, if its not installed you need to install it fist. Once installed open it an go to Configuration, in here you will see "CM106 Like Sound Device", select the folowing profile -> Analog Sorround 5.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IE558) Input.

Probably will not work at this point, but just open System Settings an go to Sound, and on the tab Output select the new profile CM106 Like Sound Device Analog Sorround 5.1. For microfon go to tab Input and select Microfon CM106 Like Sound Device.

I hope this is usefull sice on windows the vibration does not work even with the driver installed.

Comment: You're not describing the setup of a device driver but the configuration of *PulseAudio*, an audio server sitting on top of the audio device driver. Please address that in your question. Otherwise someone is likely to flag your answer as unrelated.

Comment: yes sir you are right, but olso wrong, im have just configured the pulse audio for the heaphones that i bought, since there is no actual driver made specialy for this heaphones.  the first post does not says how to install the driver but instead how to configure the headphones